# Google Sheets Script Error - cell.setHorizontalAlignment(SpreadsheetApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)

Tags: javascript, css, google-sheets, horizontal-scaling

I'm stuck with this script here where it keeps giving the error mentioned in the title.

Title: cell.setHorizontalAlignment(SpreadsheetApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)

```
function Font1() {
  // 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange('B2:D1004');
  cell.setFontWeight('bold');
  cell.setFontColor('#000000')
  cell.setFontSize(10)
  cell.setHorizontalAlignment(SpreadsheetApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "HorizontalAlignment" enum anywhere in the Google documentation for SpreadsheetApp (there is one for DocumentApp though), so I doubt what you're doing would work unless it's an undocumented enum.

Try just using "left", "center", or "right", as per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setHorizontalAlignment(String))

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
```

Comment: @WaleedArRehman if it answers your question, please upvote and mark as "correct". :)

Comment: Trying to but I'm not allowed yet, as soon as I am I'll do so.

Answer (score 0):

Change last line to:

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
```